# .Net 3.5 VS 2008 invalid token 'out' error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, token, sharpmap

I am trying to compile [SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap) for .Net 3.5, I have sorted through most of the errors and the only error I get at the moment is:

> Invalid token 'out' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Type expected

The error is situated at the beginning (line 36) of [this file](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap/blob/Branches/1.0/SharpMap/Utilities/Indexing/SpatialIndexing.cs). Here is the code (error in first line).

```
public interface ISpatialIndexItem<out TOid>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object's identifier
    /// </summary>
    TOid ID { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the spatial extent of the object
    /// </summary>
    Envelope Box { get; }
}
```

Also, I was unable to find out what is **TOid** and what library it is coming from.
I am using VS 2008 .Net 3.5 and I can't upgrade due to specifics of the project I am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Covariant and contravariant generic type parameters (the `out`) were new in .NET 4.0 and C# 4, so you can't use that. You could just remove the `out`, but some other pieces may then refuse to work :/ There isn't an easy fix for that, except perhaps manual casting.

`TOid` isn't coming from anywhere; it is the generic type parameter. By comparison, it is the `T` in `List<T>`; it is *whatever the caller wants it to be*. If the caller cites `ISpatialIndexItem<int>`, then `TOid` is `int`.